# How to allow unauthenticated users to view the root of the application

Tags: cakephp

In the `AppController.php`, I try to make the root of the application (`http://www.myappdomain.com`) visible to all.

```
   public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');//Allowed content for not authenticated visitors
    }
```

But this doesn't show me the root of my application, when I type `http://www.myappdomain.com` it redirects me to login page since I put all controllers hidden for unauthenticated users, but I still need to make the root visible. Am I missing something? Thanx.

Note: I am using cakePHP `v2.3.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't allow `index` in the `AppController.php` that will make it visible for every controller in the whole website. Add the `allow('index')` in the `beforeFilter` of the specific controller that is used to render the root.